# How to compare two datasets using GAMs? Wald's test?

Tags: generalized-additive-model

I have two datasets that have the same type of predictors. For dataset A there is a biological manipulation and for dataset B there is not (B is the control for A).

I have collected each dataset at different parameter values (let's say C1, C2, C3, ...) and see that there is a "qualitative" difference between the data from A and data from B. I'm trying to see if I can do a statistical test to see that there are differences between these two datasets using GAMs.

I was recommended GAMs because of the work in a paper (https://www.jneurosci.org/content/jneuro/37/37/9037.full.pdf) that used a similar approach to compare the two datasets.

What I don't really understand is that they get two GAMs, one for each dataset and then use a Wald's test to compare the two GAMs. I just don't really understand how the Wald's test fit into this. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks